# Q.fail not working when using Q.allSettled

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

When using `Q.allSettled`, I can't use `Q.fail` to get the error.

If i have `promises` which contains a promise that is eventually rejected, this code never gets in the `.fail` block

```
Q.allSettled(promises)
    .then(function () {
        // Handle success
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        console.log('IN ERRR', err);
    });
});
```

The documentation for `.allSettled` has this as the example:

```
Q.allSettled(promises)
.then(function (results) {
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        if (result.state === "fulfilled") {
            var value = result.value;
        } else {
            var reason = result.reason;
        }
    });
});
```

Is this expected behavior for the `.allSettled` function to not get inside a `.fail` block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the promise returned by `.allSettled()` is fulfilled with an array of all of the results, whether they were fulfillments or rejections.

If the returned promise somehow caused entry into both the `.then()` handler *and* the `.fail()` handler, then that would lead to some pretty confusing program flow and would violate the promise contract.

If you wanted to, you could do this, though:

```
Q.allSettled(promises)
.then(function (results) {
    results
        .filter(function (result) { 
            return result.state === "fulfilled"; 
        })
        .forEach(function (result) {
            // handle each success
        });

    throw results.filter(function (result) {
        return result.state !== "fulfilled";
    });
})
.fail(function (err) {
    console.log('IN ERRR', err);
});
```